# python Serialport Write Decimal

Tags: python, string, serial-port, decimal

How to print decimal + string from serial port together?

```
st = "value"
dc=Decimal("12")
if(s.isOpen()==False)
   s.open()
s.write(st+dc)
s.close()
```

Comment: We need more information. What is `s`? We would like to see the import statement and definition of that variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with serial ports. You attempt to concatenate a string and a Decimal, which cannot be done directly. You must convert the Decimal to a string and then concatenate the strings:

```
st + str(dc)
#'value12'
```